is there a default folder /etc/bin in ubuntu 24.04
I recently tried to move an executable to somewhere as part of the PATH and I accidentally renamed it and put it as /etc/bin instead of inside /etc/bin :
sudo mv exec /etc/bin

Now my /etc/bin is the executable and I am not sure if i just overridden a folder with an executable or not ? Could that even happen and if so, what did I lose from the /etc/bin

The /etc/ folder and its sub-folders are exclusively for Editable Text Configuration files. Putting a bin folder and executable files in it goes against Linux system files and folder standards. See this Q&A for where to keep your personal executable files.

See https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-directory-structure/ for a primer on the Linux system folder structure.

@user68186 yes, but i don't know exactly about the Ubuntu server instance I have running, they do change some aspects.

No. bin directory has nothing to do in the root of /etc/. The advice of the FSH would be to have bin in the root (/bin) and in /usr/ (same goes for sbin).
All you did was move the file exec to /etc/ and name it bin.
Reversal:
cd /etc/
mv bin /org/dir/exec

where /org/dir is where you had exec before the `mv.

thanks great to know i didn't lose access to anything.

cd /etc/binwill probably not work as that is a file... ;-)
